# bypass router to access local ftp sharing

Tags: routing, mikrotik-routeros

Recently I configured a simple basic VLAN setup on Cisco 3750 switch and connected it with a Mikrotik Routerboard using a trunk port. VLAN setup is as follows.

Mikrotik Router LAN Port = 10.0.0.0.1/24 [Connected with Cisco 3750 Port 1 , trunk]

Cisco 3750 
Port 1 = Trunk, connected with Mikrotik
Port 2 = Vlan10 = 10.1.0.0/24 [User Group 1]
Port 3 = Vlan20 = 10.2.0.0/24 [User Group 2] 
Port 3 = Vlan30 = 10.3.0.0/24 [FTP Media Sharing Server 1]
Port 4 = Vlan40 = 10.4.0.0/24 [FTP Media Sharing Server 2]

The PPPoE Server is configured on RB & All users internet is working fine via dialing into it. and they are able to ping each other. This part is ok ,

Now the problem is if user starts download heavy files from FTP Media Sharing Server 1/2 , there traffic is passing through the Mikrotik router which puts load on the RB's CPU (as the trunk traffic bandwidth reaches in GB which chocks the Mikrotik port traffic as well]

Is there any way User Group can access FTP media sharing without going through the Mikrotik router, and somehow connect with FTP locally by switch port directly?

Answer (score 4):

No, the purpose of a vLAN is to segregate the network. You have successfully segregated the network.

Now, you have to route the two networks together for them to communicate.

- Place the users and FTP servers on the same network if you wish for
  them to communicate directly.
- Alternatively, upgrade your Mikrotik to better hardware to handle the load.
- Or, segregate the network differently so the inter-network routing is offloaded on a different device.

Comment: I cant place the user & ftp on same subnet because, all vlans have /24 subnet, and ftp is different vlan with different subnet. even if I upgrade the router hardware, traffic is massive, it will chock eventually. The alternate solution should be to maek switch default gateway for all traffic, and route all unknown traffic (internet) to router. inter vlan routing i guess?

Comment: number of vlans are over 50.